# How to create a database snapshot in SQL Server with SSMS GUI, not SQL code

Tags: sql-server-2005, snapshot

How to create a database snapshot in SQL Server with SSMS GUI? I can't find the menu of that action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from the [msdn article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876(SQL.90).aspx) -

"The only way to create a snapshot is to use Transact-SQL."

Comment: Quite disappointing that there's no SSMS GUI support for this functionality. Bad Microsoft, bad! *slaps*